# The integral of an hadamard product and a nonlinear point wise function

Tags: integration, derivatives, matrix-calculus, hadamard-product

How do you compute L, the function whose partial derivative with respect to W is as below?

[image]

Where B and W are matrices, and e and h are vectors. f is a pointwise nonlinear, but differentiable function. I am pretty new to matrix calculus, but I couldn't find anything in [The Matrix Cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf) that I could directly use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convenience, define the variables
$$\eqalign{
 x &= Wh \cr
 y &= Be \cr
 Y &= {\rm Diag}(y) \cr
 g=g(x) &= f^\prime(x) \cr
\cr
}$$
Now reformulate the differential of $L$ 
$$\eqalign{
 dL &= \frac{\partial L}{\partial W}:dW \cr
    &= Ygh^T:dW \cr
    &= Yg:dWh \cr
    &= Yg:dx \cr
    &= y\odot g:dx \cr
    &= y:g\odot dx \cr
    &= y:df \cr
}$$
Now we can integrate
$$\eqalign{
 L &= \int dL \cr
 &= y:\int df \cr
 &= y:f \cr
 &= y^Tf \cr\cr
}$$
We can pull $y$ out of the integral because it is independent of $(W,h,x)$.

In some of the steps, we made use of the fact that the elementwise/Hadamard product (denoted by $\odot$) and the inner/Frobenius product (denoted by $:$) commute with themselves and each other.

For complete generality, we should include a constant of integration
$$L = y^T(f+c)$$

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! Did you consult any resources that might help me do this kind of thing in the future?